# Streaming operators usage in the context of serializers in PHY

Tags: system-verilog

I have 8:1 serializers and de-serializers based on the data width in our RTL code.As of now we are using **for** loops for the data path loading and data path reading from the serializers. Can we use streaming operators for this functionality.

Iam new to the streaming operators so exactly i am not getting how to use them in this context.

```
input  [8*DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_from_user; //WRITE DATA 
output [8*DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_to_user;   //READ DATA
output [7:0]              data_to_phy_serializer     [DATA_WIDTH-1:0];
input  [7:0]              data_from_phy_deserializer [DATA_WIDTH-1:0];

//WRITE DATA PATH FLOW
always@(posedge clk) begin:WRITE_PATH
  for(i = 0 ; i < DATA_WIDTH ; i =  i+ 1 )
        data_to_phy_serializer[i]  = '{
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*7 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*6 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*5 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*4 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*3 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*2 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*1 + i],
                                         data_from_user[DATA_WIDTH*0 + i]
                                       } ;
  end

//READ DATA PATH FLOW
 always@(posedge clk) begin:READ_PATH
    for(j= 0 ; j < DATA_WIDTH ; j = j + 1)begin
      {
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*7],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*6],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*5],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*4],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*3],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*2],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*1],
       data_to_user[j+DATA_WIDTH*0]
      }                         <= #TCQ data_from_phy_deserializer[j] ;
     end
```

input will be in the form of 8 data words concatenated and i need to the send the data to PHY of each data bit separately by picking up that elements correspondingly from the input data.

this code is working fine but only doubt is can i use streaming operators in this context  . Please don't tell the basics of streaming operators, like its for packed to unpacked conversions and viceversa. I need to stream the data for PHY . if i can use streaming operators in this context it will help me so much.

example code for write data path of 4 bit data width to 8:1 serializers

```
   //write data for data width of 4
assign [8*4 -1:0] data = {4'hF,4'hE,4'hD,4'hC,4'hB,4'hA,4'h9,4'h8};

//so now data to each data bit serializer will be
//8:1 data for serializers of
//              bit-- 3-- 2-- 1-- 0
//              4'b___1___1___1___1
//              4'b___1___1___1___0
//              4'b___1___1___0___1
//              4'b___1___1___0___0
//              4'b___1___0___1___1
//              4'b___1___0___1___0
//              4'b___1___0___0___1
//              4'b___1___0___0___0
//  data for serializer of bit 0 is 8'b10101010
//  data for serializer of bit 1 is 8'b11001100
//  data for serializer of bit 2 is 8'b11110000
//  data for serializer of bit 3 is 8'b11111111

assign [7:0] data_to_phy_serializers [3:0] = '{
                                                    8'b11111111,
                                                    8'b11110000,
                                                    8'b11001100,
                                                    8'b10101010
                                              };
```

Comment: i think in both ways we can use streaming operator for packed to unpacked and unpacked to packed arrays

Comment: https://www.amiq.com/consulting/2017/05/29/how-to-pack-data-using-systemverilog-streaming-operators/

Comment: https://www.amiq.com/consulting/2017/06/23/how-to-unpack-data-using-the-systemverilog-streaming-operators/

Comment: @RAMAKRISHNAMEDA all the examples you referenced are use packed data only.

Comment: @Serge, So in this context can we use streaming operator ??

Comment: You're right. Streaming works both ways. I've learnt something.

Comment: Streaming works with any bit-stream type as defined in *6.24.3 Bit-stream casting*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it in both cases.I guess this will work:

```
data_to_phy_serializer = {>>{data_from_user}};
```

and

```
data_to_user <= #TCD {>>{data_from_phy_deserializer}};
```

I have a small experimental example here which you can play with.

```
module ab;
  logic [3:0][1:0]a;
  logic [3:0]b[1:0];
  logic [3:0][1:0]c;

  initial begin
    a = 8'hAB;
    b = {>>{a}};
    c = {>>{b}};

    $displayh(a,b[1],b[0],c);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: I think this not the solution in this context , please look into the example data flow i have edited in the question.the solution u provided is packed to unpacked conversion

Comment: the solution u provided will give data as                                                                                             // 8'b1111_1110
// 8'b1101_1100
// 8'b1011_1010
// 8'b1001_1000
 but actual data required is                                                                                                  
 // 8'b1111_1111
 // 8'b1111_0000
 // 8'b1100_1100
 // 8'b1010_1010

Comment: @RAMAKRISHNAMEDA you have significantly changed the example. So, the answer does not apply any longer.

Comment: Sry for that I have written modified version of code and I realised I didn't shown the actual intent of code